# How to configure ST_GEOMETRY Access for Oracle 64 bit?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, 64bit

I'm trying to configure the Oracle extproc to access the geodatabase with SQL, using the [documentation here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002n00000091000000).

This is a Windows 2008 R2 server with 64 bit, and the Oracle server is also 64 bit.

I'm still getting the dreaded `ORA-28595: Extproc agent : Invalid DLL Path` when I run a spatial SQL query.

I tried to debug the issue by loading the dll using dependency walker, and saw that it was trying to load 64 bit dlls.

I know that SDE is still 32 bit, so I'm assuming that 32 bit-64 bit conflict is the cause of the problem.

I have configured this with a 32 bit Oracle RDBMS in the past.

Has anyone configured Oracle extproc to access the geodatabase with SQL with Oracle 64 bit?

Comment: ArcSDE hasn't permitted 32-bit since 10.1 was released. What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I've never had hs/admin configuration *not* work.  What does `SELECT * FROM user_libraries` as SDE return?

Comment: @Vince: You are right; the ArcSDE Binary is 64 bit. I'll do the query from your comment and get back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ArcGIS has supported 64-bit Oracle 11g since 9.3.1.  In fact, ArcGIS Server has been exclusively 64-bit since 10.1 was released (Desktop continues to be 32-bit, so that might be the cause of this confusion).

Configuring the SDE.ST_GEOMETRY custom datatype for use with Oracle 11g clients other than ArcGIS requires up to four steps:

1. Installing the datatype (usually in conjunction with the geodatabase install)
2. Copying the appropriate DLL from the Desktop 10.*n*\DatabaseSupport folder to the database server (if not local)
3. Configuring the Oracle installation to honor the ST_GEOMETRY DLL (which is described in the link you provided)
4. Adjusting the user library path to point to the actual DLL install location (if non-local, or the location configured above is different than the value populated at installation)

This last step is described in [Knowledge Base article 35473](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/35473), and can be summarized:

```
sqlplus sde/password

SQL> SELECT library_name, file_spec FROM user_libraries;

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY st_shapelib
  2  AS 'C:\actual\DLL\location\st_shapelib.dll';
  3  /

SQL> SELECT object_name FROM user_objects WHERE status = 'INVALID';
```

If that last query comes back with errors, then you'll need to recompile the SDE packages (easiest as SYS with `EXECUTE sys.utl_recomp.recomp_serial('SDE');` ).  If there are no invalid objects, you should be able to validate ST_GEOMETRY access with:

```
SQL> SELECT sde.ST_AsText(SDE.ST_Geometry('POINT (10 10)', 0)) FROM dual;
```

Comment: Your answer has been very helpful. It solved my issue. The only way I diverted from this answer is that the reconciliation has to be done by the sys user.

Comment: I did write that recompilation must be done as SYS.